# Picture in Picture (Pip) always has padding around in Flutter (android)

Tags: android, flutter, picture-in-picture, android-picture-in-picture

I use the below mentioned code snippet to display the Picture in Picture. I use this to display my video screen. This works fine but I see a padding (Green border) around my picture in picture view. I am launching this picture in picture code from my flutter application. Appricates for any clues to solve this issue.

Code:

```
    pipParams = PictureInPictureParams.Builder()
        .build()
    enterPictureInPictureMode(pipParams!!)
```

Problem reference screen: (Green border in the below screen)

[image]

Note: This behaviour is happening with Samsung s10 Edge device.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly mention how did you use the pip feature and which video player package are you using ?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).